# Mean Curvature flow: singularities and rescaling procedure

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

In the context of Mean Curvature Flow (MCF), it's explained that in order to study the development of singularities, two tools are necessary: the monotonicity formula of Huisken and the rescaling procedure. However, I cannot understand... why does rescaling allow us to understand something about the singularities? What are we actually doing?

I would be grateful if someone could clarify this for me, even without excessive mathematical formalism. It's the intuitive concept that I lack.

Comment: Do you know what is the rescaling process at all? Did you read the work of Huisken?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rescaling process, to be honest. Could you please provide me with some references?

Comment: You may start with the first one by Huisken [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Asymptotic-behavior-for-singularities-of-the-flow-Huisken/897fc1c3d98dbf107afdac15b3e1b7d3055604d5). This is where he first derive the monotonicity formula and perform a re-scaling procedure. The study of singularities had been THE central object in MCF for the last three decades, it is impossible to summarize here the whole story.